# r dplyr filter error - Column has unsupported type

Tags: r, dplyr

**Situation**

I have a data frame `df` with two variables, `ReportYear` and `Salary`.

```
dput(df)

structure(list(ReportYear = structure(c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012), class = c("summaryDefault", "table"
)), Salary = structure(c(198000, 495500, 745000, 1417000, 1662000, 
5483000, 260100, 460000, 697000, 1595000, 2160000, 5778000, 331000, 
790000, 1260000, 1736000, 1670000, 9310000, 270000, 459500, 602000, 
1355000, 984200, 6191000, 290000, 463200, 564500, 1420000, 779500, 
6779000, 650300, 1448000, 2076000, 2907000, 3894000, 6938000, 
157000, 404800, 481000, 1074000, 1199000, 4603000), class = c("summaryDefault", 
"table"))), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("ReportYear", 
"Salary"))
```

I'm trying to `filter` the data, but get an error:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(df, Salary > 10)
Error: column 'ReportYear' has unsupported type
```

**Question**

Does anyone know why my `ReportYear` is the wrong type? Is it to do with the "list" structure, and if so how do I resolve it so that I can `filter` the data?

**Other Notes**

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   42 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ReportYear:Classes 'summaryDefault', 'table'  num [1:42] 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ Salary    :Classes 'summaryDefault', 'table'  num [1:42] 198000 495500 745000 1417000 1662000     ... 
>
```

The data was generated by `summary`.

Comment: I'm betting it's the wrong type because the columns came from `summary.default`, see here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html.  It would help to know how you created the data

Comment: Yes, the data comes from `summary`, in particular: `ddply(data_df, .(Pos), numcolwise(summary))`. (In my question I've omitted other variables).

Comment: I see.  You know in `dplyr` nowadays you hardly ever need to use `ddply` anymore

Comment: No I didn't know that; I'm still learning R :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be of the wrong type because the columns came from `summary.default`.  See the *Value* section of the [`summary()` help file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/summary.html).

> The default method returns an object of class c("summaryDefault", "table") which has a specialized print method.

It would help to know how you created the data in the first place, but you can remove these classes with `unclass` then your code will work fine.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, unclass)
filter(df, Salary > 10)
```

I'm not certain if this is standard expected behavior or not.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thanks.

Comment: (-1) not enough pipes. Kidding, of course. This seems a little like possibly a bug.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - possibly. Been messing around and I haven't yet discovered this error in any other `dplyr` functions.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell how your columns ended up being of classes "SummaryDefault" and "table" without knowing how you created the data..

To resolve the filter problem and turn the columns back to numeric type, you can use `mutate_each` like this for example:

```
mutate_each(df, funs(as.numeric)) %>% filter(Salary > 10)
```